# Show all required fields on from submit at once html

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui

I am using  **HTML reqired**
 because the UI is good.

[image]

I want to see all the fields which are **required** at once. how can I do that.?

Please find the fiddle:
[**JS Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/1225/)

When we submit the form it is showing the only one which comes first, I want to show all with these small tooltips how can I do that..?

From the fiddle when submitting the form without entering anything it should show both tooltips because both are required,

similarly apart from fiddle any number of required fields it should show all at once...! is it possible.?

Code:

```
$( "form" ).kendoValidator({
    messages: {
        required: function( input ) {
            var element = input[ 0 ],
                label = $( element.form ).find( "[for=" + element.id + "]" );
            return label.text().replace( ":", "" ) + " is required.";
        },
        email: "Please provide a valid email address"
    }
});

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function() {
    alert( "Successful submission" );
});
```

Comment: Try using selectors, like `$('form').find('[required]:visible');`

Comment: can u give the fiddle example i am not getting what u r trying to say

Comment: You can use validator as specified in [documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index)

Comment: In your image, its normal for validation message not the kendo error message

Comment: Normal validation message is sufficient but it should show how many fields are required at once(when we click submit) .!!

Comment: Did you look at `ValidationSummary`?